# Transit visa mainland China, Qingdao

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, china, twov

I'm an Indian passport holder. I'm having a flight (Shandong airlines)

- Osaka (KIX, 12:55) - Qingdao (TAO, 14:45)   - Flight number SC8092
- 15 hr layover in Qingdao
- Qingdao (TAO, 06:00) - New Delhi (DEL, 14:00) - Flight number SC8829

My second flight SC8829 is also making a 1.5hr stop at Kunming before again starting to New Delhi. The Kunming stop was not shown as a layover while I was booking the flight, it was just said "will stop at Kunming for 1.5hr"

Should I take a transit visa in Qingdao to board flight in Qingdao if Im not planning to go out of airport?

Answer (score 1):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward
>   air, cruise or train ticket to a third country within 24 hours can obtain an entry permit on arrival. They must have
>   documents required for the next destination.

In other words, since you're transiting for less than 24 hours, you do not need a visa even if clearing immigration. However, be prepared for check-in staff at KIX possibly not being aware of this; in that case, ask a good English-speaking agent to check TIMATIC (NA=IN, TR=CN)

Comment: Inorder to take entry permit, will I also be needing hotel reservation ?

Comment: @HariPrasad No, there's no such requirement (or else it would say so in TIMATIC)